# Close Chrome Print Preview Dialogue Box Using Javascipt

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

window.print() method will open print preview dialogue box. How to close that box using javascript.

Can we use Custom Events to dispatch "esc key", but don't know where to dispatch(Element).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you can't do this. Just like alert dialog, the print dialog will block the browser until you click cancel button or save button. You can try to run some codes when the print dialog is hanging, then you will find you can just input the codes in console but there is no output and the codes are not running. So I think you can't do that using javascript.